# has deleting node in a binary search tree Displacement feature?

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics, trees

I am developing an academic project about graph and tree theory.I searched a lot but I didn't find a clear answer. In a part of project we want to delete some nodes from tree for example we want to delete nodes A and B.I want to know that if we Delete A and then B does It give us exactly the same tree that We will produce when We Delete B and then A and if yes is there any proof or anything that can make sure us about that.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by **deleting**? What kind of search tree are you using (balanced?, keys in all nodes or just the leaves?)

Comment: a simple binary search tree keys in all nodes(include leaves).being balance is not required.

Comment: deleting means that for example detele('4') removes node with key 4  from our tree.

Answer (score 1):

finally i will find the answer!
Deletion (in general) is not commutative. Here is a counterexample:

```
    4
   / \
  3   7
     /
    6
```

**What if we delete 4 and then 3?**

When we delete 4, we get 6 as the new root:

```
   6
  / \
 3   7
```

Deleting 3 doesn't change the tree, but gives us this:

```
  6
   \
    7
```

**What if we delete 3 and then 4?**

When we delete 3 the tree doesn't change:

```
 4
  \
   7
  /
 6
```

However, when we now delete 4, the new root becomes 7:

```
  7
 /
6
```

The two resulting trees are not the same, therefore deletion is not commutative.

reference and more details : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990486/deletion-procedure-for-a-binary-search-tree